# Google Api Client sometime NULL in onConnected

Tags: android, google-api-client

I implement `GoogleApiClient` as bellow:

```
 mGoogleApiClient = new GoogleApiClient.Builder(this)
                .enableAutoManage(this, 0 /* clientId */, this)
                .addApi(LocationServices.API)
                .addApi(Places.GEO_DATA_API)
                .addConnectionCallbacks(this)
                .build();
```

But in `onConnected` method I check mGoogleApiClient => value null.
In this case I try to re-build googleApiClient but I get error:

```
  java.lang.IllegalStateException: Already managing a GoogleApiClient with id 0
```

Please help me understand why mGoogleApiClient is sometimes NULL althought it's connected :|. (Notes. I checked all source code, I never set GoogleApiClient to NULL).

Thanks!

**Update**

My problem now solved after I try use latest version of play-service.

Thanks everybody for help.

Comment: I have the same issue but i am using google play servcies, 8.4.0 latest version, but this issue still happening

Answer (score 36):

I had the same problem. All I did to solve it is remove `.enableAutoManage(this, 0 /* clientId */, this)` because it just doesn't work properly from what I assumed. Then, override these methods in your activity:

```
@Override
public void onStart() {
    super.onStart();
    if (mGoogleApiClient != null) {
        mGoogleApiClient.connect();
    }
}

@Override
public void onStop() {
    if (mGoogleApiClient != null && mGoogleApiClient.isConnected()) {
        mGoogleApiClient.disconnect();
    }
    super.onStop();
}
```

Technically, that is what `.enableAutoManage(this, 0 /* clientId */, this)` was supposed to do, except that now, everything works as it should.

Answer (score 13):

[Documentation](https://developers.google.com/android/reference/com/google/android/gms/common/api/GoogleApiClient.Builder) says: At any given time, only one auto-managed client is allowed per id. To reuse an id you must first call `stopAutoManage(FragmentActivity)` on the previous client.

What I personally do is making a call to bellow method before I leave the activity, in which I am using the Google Api Client.

```
private void stopAutoManage() {
    if (mGoogleApiClient != null)
        mGoogleApiClient.stopAutoManage(mActivity);
}
```

Comment: Still get same error, can you check [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56037170/google-api-client-already-managing-with-id-0) please @abedfar

Answer (score 6):

I think you'd better watch this reference.

[reference page of "public GoogleApiClient.Builder enableAutoManage"](https://developer.android.com/reference/com/google/android/gms/common/api/GoogleApiClient.Builder.html#enableAutoManage(android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity,%20int,%20com.google.android.gms.common.api.GoogleApiClient.OnConnectionFailedListener))

In this page shows that, through IllegalStateException if clientId is already being auto-managed. 
So, check on your code with

```
                .enableAutoManage(this, 0 /* clientId */, this)
```

I think if exception on your code, it could return zero as not completed.

Comment: It's only happen if I rebuild Google API. But current I build it complete. method "onConnected" called. But mGooogleApiClient is NULL :|
I debug & check it many time. (it's not always happend. Feq about 1/10).

Comment: I see why error "  java.lang.IllegalStateException: Already managing a GoogleApiClient with id 0" happend. I care about why mGoogleApiClient have value NULL in onConnected method :|, please help. Thanks

Answer (score 2):

If u are facing this problem when u try to reinitialize mGoogleApiClient, then just remove

`.enableAutoManage(this, 0 /* clientId */, this)`

Use

```
mGoogleApiClient = new GoogleApiClient.Builder(this)
            .addApi(LocationServices.API)
            .addApi(Places.GEO_DATA_API)
            .addConnectionCallbacks(this)
            .build();
```

and it will work fine

Comment: Nothing happens when I remove enableAutoManage, but works when I add it

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem (Already managing a GoogleApiClient with id 0) in a fragment, and finally I resolved it :

- Override `onStart()` and `onStop()` normally
- Add in `onStop()` call  `yourApiGoogle.stopAutoManage(context);`

Have a nice day...

Answer (score 0):

`build()` calls `onConnected` immediately if you are already connected. Therefore, your variable might be null.

Better use

```
mGoogleApiClient = new GoogleApiClient.Builder(this)
            .enableAutoManage(this, 0 /* clientId */, this)
            .addApi(LocationServices.API)
            .addApi(Places.GEO_DATA_API)
            .addConnectionCallbacks(this);
mGoogleApiClient.build();
```