# Open a wear activity from a wear notification action button

Tags: android, android-notifications, wear-os, android-wear-data-api, android-wear-notification

All im trying to do is set it up so that when you click one of the action buttons on the notification it opens a wear activity ive looked up how to do this a bunch over the past day and i keep winding up with the same onconnected: null issue. i cant seem to progress past this problem thanks in advance for any help.

`PutDataMapRequest dataMapRequest = PutDataMapRequest.create("/notification");
            dataMapRequest.getDataMap().putDouble("timestamp", System.currentTimeMillis());
            dataMapRequest.getDataMap().putString("title", "This is the title");
            dataMapRequest.getDataMap().putString("content", "This is a notification with some text.");
            PutDataRequest putDataRequest = dataMapRequest.asPutDataRequest();
            Wearable.DataApi.putDataItem(mGoogleApiClient, putDataRequest);`

Comment: Is this a notification you're generating from the handheld, or entirely on the wearable? It might also help if you posted the code you're using to create the notification.

Comment: ok i just added the code i use for notifications however becuase its not connecting properly i dont think it even goes through

Comment: OK, why are you sending this through the Data API rather than just letting the Wear system show a notification on the watch for you? [http://developer.android.com/training/wearables/notifications] And if your DataMap isn't getting to the wearable, then that's a whole 'nother issue - nothing to do with notifications. [http://developer.android.com/training/wearables/data-layer]

Comment: I was able to create a notification in a separate method but essentially what I'm trying to do is open a wear activity through either a wear notification or on the handheld app I'm simply came across this way of creating a notification while searching for his to open a wear activity through a notification

Comment: Also just a heads up I am fairly new to wear development which is probably why I missed that

Answer (score 0):

About the GoogleApiClient being null at `onConnected`, try calling `mGoogleApiClient.connect()` at **onStart** and `mGoogleApiClient.disconnect()` at **onStop**, as adviced in the [documentation](http://developer.android.com/training/wearables/data-layer/events.html).

If you have used `enableAutoManage`, also remove it as in this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29619208/google-api-client-sometime-null-in-onconnected).

Comment: Thanks I think I've got the connection established but back to the main question how do I open the wear app from my handheld app

Comment: You can send a message using the `MessageApi` from your phone to your wearable. The wearable would be listening for messages with `WearableListenerService` declared in the wear manifest with the BIND_LISTENER action. When the wearable receives the message there, it will start an activity of your choice or fire a notification which will be created in the wearable so its actions will start wearable side activities. Check the [documentation](http://developer.android.com/training/wearables/data-layer/index.html) for more implementation details.